# Two lists from list comprehension in python language

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have file

```
#Comment
Name1;Value1
Name2;Value2
```

I would like to read the file, first line should be passed, then have two lists in result. One of them will contain only names, like (Name1, Name2) and another will contain only values, like (Value1, Value2).

Perhaps here list comprehension can be used. 
Is it possible to get two lists from one list comprehension command in python language?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like a cvs file, how about to use the cvs module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to transform your data from rows into columns. Use `zip()` for that, and the `csv` module to read the file:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)  # skip first line

    names, values = zip(*reader)
```

No list comprehensions required.